# Magento child html -- get parent caller

Tags: php, magento, enterprise, mage

I am in the template file `price.phtml`.  I would like to have some line of code that looks at the parent that is calling the block and do some behavior based on that.  Essentially if the parent is a catalog list page, I want a `from:`  tag to be added to the price.  If the parent is `configurable.phtml`, I want to simply display the price as normal.

I already have the code to add the `from:` to the price but I need the if statement to tell what the parent caller is.

I have seen something like `::parent` before when perusing Mage files, but I don't know if that is applicable here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YOu can get reference to a block's parent block from a phtml by calling

```
$parent = $this->getParentBlock();
```

The calls to `parent::someMethod` have nothing to do with blocks, or with Magento.  They're PHP constructs, used to indicate you want to call a method on the parent class.

Answer (score 7):

here is a bunch of methods that can help you understanding which kind of page you are visualizing in Magento:

- Current CMS Page: `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();`
- Current Route: `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();`
- Current Controller: `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName();`
- Current Action: `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName();`

So, for example, if you want to understand you are in a **catalog list page** you can use the **last three** in order to check whether the route is **catalog**, the controller is **category** and the action is **view**.

Another method would consist in checking for the presence of a **catalog_category_view**  layout **handle** in the array of current layout handles that you can retrieve in the following way from a Block or a Template: `$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()`

Hope it helps.

Regards, Alessandro